# Is there a CGAL function to check whether holes are actually inside a polygon with holes or to to check whether a polygon with holes is valid?

Tags: c++, cgal

I am working with Polygon_with_holes_2. Unfortunately, it seems so that a Polygon_with_holes_2 accepts holes that lie outside the polygon too.

Hence, I need to make sure all the holes are inside the outer boundary of the Polygon_with_holes_2.

Is there any way to do this rather than simply checking whether each point of each holes lies within the polygon?

I am currently using the following the following method to check whether a Polygon_with_holes_2 is valid or not. However, it seems a bit primitive.

```
bool is_valid_pwh(Polygon_with_holes pwh)
{

  for (auto hi = pwh.holes_begin(); hi != pwh.holes_end(); ++hi) {

    for (auto point : *hi) {

      if (CGAL::oriented_side(point, pwh.outer_boundary()) != 1) {

          return false;

      }

    }

  }

  return true;

}
```

Comment: See the chapter "2D Regularized Boolean Set-Operations".

Comment: See, in particular, the unpublished free function is_valid_polygon_with_holes() defined in Boolean_set_operations_2/Gps_polygon_validation.h. In DEBUG mode this function is invoked for every polygon with holes that is an operand of a Boolean set operation.